# Issues in developing web scraper

Tags: javascript, xss, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to develop a platform where users can enter a URL and then my website will open the webpage in an `iframe`. Now the user can modify his website by simply right clicking and I will provide him options like "remove this element", "copy this element". I am almost through. Many of the websites are opening perfectly in `iframe` but for a few websites some errors have shown up. I could not identify the reason so asking for your help.

I have solved other issues like XSS problem.
Here is the procedure I have followed :-
Used JavaScript and sent the request to my Java server which makes connection to the URL specified by the user and fetches the HTML and then use Jsoup HTML parser to convert relative URLs into absolute URLs and then save the HTML to my disk in Java. And then I render the saved HTML into my `iframe`.

Is somewhere wrong ?
A few websites are working perfectly but a few are not.

For example:-
When I tried to open http://www.snapdeal.com it gave me the 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paddingTop' of undefined`
error. I don't understand why this is happening..

**Update**
I really wonder how this is implemented? @ http://www.proxywebsites.in/browse.php?u=Oi8vd3d3LnNuYXBkZWFsLmNvbQ%3D%3D&b=13&f=norefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one more thing. In your proxy script you are saving your webpage on your disk and then loading into iframe. I think instead of loading the page you saved on disk in iframe try to open that page in browser. All those sites that restirct their page to be loaded into iframe will now get opened without any error.
Try this I think it an work

Comment: Hi, Its working for most of the sites now But still snapdeal.com is throwing same error and its background image is not loading into my page..

Answer (score 1):

2 issues, pick any you like:

- your server side proxy code contains bugs
- plenty of sites have either explicit frame-break code or at least expect to be top level frame.

Comment: I have posted my server side code and now after being suggested by Lina, i am not loading the page into iframe but opening the page in browser, its not working for few site. Do you have any idea about some other possible mistake

Answer (score 0):

My Proxy Server side code :-

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
    String dirName = df.format(new Date());

    String dirPath = "C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/offlineWeb/" + dirName;
    String serverName = "http://localhost:8080/offlineWeb/" + dirName;

    boolean directoryCreated = new File(dirPath).mkdir();
    if (!directoryCreated) 
        log.error("Error in creating directory");

    String html = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get().html();
    doc = Jsoup.parse(html, url);

    links = doc.select("link");
    scripts = doc.select("script");    
    images = doc.select("img");

for (Element element : links) {
        String linkHref = element.attr("abs:href");
        if (linkHref != "") {
            element.attr("href", linkHref);
        }
}

for (Element element : scripts) {
    String scriptSrc = element.attr("abs:src");
    if (scriptSrc != "") {
        element.attr("src", scriptSrc);
    }
}

for (Element element : images) {
    String imgSrc = element.attr("abs:src");
        if (imgSrc != "") {
            element.attr("src", imgSrc);
            log.info(imgSrc);
        }
}
```

And Now i am just returning the path where i saved my html file
That's it about my server code

Comment: Your this much of code seems correct..May be some of the websites don't allow their site to be opened in iframe. That's the only reason I can think of